# Craft Commerce - More detailed reporting

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm looking to get more detailed reporting from craft commerce. I would like to be able to see a breakdown of what we've sold in a set period of time (week, month etc) which details out products, revenue, and quantities. Right now I only have the option to see total revenue or top products

Answer (score 1):

Select the date range of your orders:

[image: select date]

Then export the line items to csv and open in excel:

[image: select line item export]

You can then use excel to create sums/grouping and charts etc.

Comment: Just found that product description and SKU are not in those exports (only purchasableId) I have added those to the export for the next commerce release.